# Vue.js app opening url links from a drop down in a new page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

my code is

```
               <div class="md-list-item-content">
                <drop-down direction="down">
                  <md-button
                    slot="title"
                    class="md-button md-button-link md-white md-simple dropdown-toggle"
                    data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="material-icons">view_day</i>
                    <p>Links</p>
                  </md-button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-with-icons">
                    <li
                      v-for="li in linksExternal"
                      :key="li.name">
                      <a :href="li.href" >
                        <i class="material-icons">{{ li.icon }}</i>                            
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </drop-down>
              </div>
```

and my script code is

```
      linksExternal: [
     { name: "NCI Dictionary",  href: "https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms target='_blank'" , icon: "dns" }
      ]
```

I have tried to add the target='_blank' in various locations such as in the HTML a tag location but it still always open in the same tab or I may not have the syntax correct.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  It this a Vue specific item or should I be doing it a different way with a function that calls a window.open?  I am trying to stay with the Vue best practices method if I can.  This should be a simple solution to look up but I have not found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to change a bit:

`href: "https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms target='_blank'"`

notice the `target='_blank'`, `target` is an attribute of the `a` element and not part of the URL

so the data need to change to something like this:

```js
linksExternal: [
  { name: "NCI Dictionary",  href: "https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms", target="_blank", icon: "dns" }
]
```

and the template to this:

```html
...
<li v-for="li in linksExternal" :key="li.name">
  <a :href="li.href" :target="li.target">
    <i class="material-icons">{{ li.icon }}</i>
  </a>
</li>
...
```

or simply if all the links will need to open in a new tab:

```html
...
<li v-for="li in linksExternal" :key="li.name">
  <a :href="li.href" target="_blank">
    <i class="material-icons">{{ li.icon }}</i>
  </a>
</li>
...
```

Comment: PERFECT-- Thank you.  In this area all need to open in a new window but I'll be able to use the other code in a different section.

Answer (score 1):

try using `target="_blank"` inside:

`<a :href="li.href" target="_blank">
  <i class="material-icons">{{ li.icon }}</i>
</a>`

Comment: happy to help anytime

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about the rest of the markup, but I suggest you remove the target part from your linksExternal object, and put it in the `<a>` element as below

```html
<a :href="li.href" target="_blank">Cool link that opens in another page</a>
```